# What is absolute path of built in System DropBox folder in android

Tags: android

I need to copy some files from sdcard to system dropbox folder from a shell script, for that i need to hardcode the absolute path of the system dropbox folder.

Comment: And the question is? And what is 'a standard service'?

Comment: I still see no question.

Comment: Why can't you, i guess you know there is a standard folder by the name DropBox to which system dumps bugreports, last_kmsg on reboot etc. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FDropBoxManager.html&ei=eFzwVLrNC9WPuATb8IGABQ&usg=AFQjCNHZ9pFyjOAfwvKy-HZpiCJnvDEqLQ&sig2=NblROtxPxhXVtVnZIrVyZgusing DropBoxManager Service. I want to know the absolute path to that folder.This is different from the DropBox app.

Comment: Please put all info in the body of your post. Make a decent description as i still can't follow you. For instance: `from where it will get picked up by another app`? Which other app?

Comment: @greenapps: I get your point but to be quite honest, my question is completely mentioned in heading itself, its a pretty simple question, description is not even needed, actually. If you know the absolute location, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: @greenapps - this question concerns built in functionality of the Android platform for saving and potentially exporting runtime issue reports.  If that is not something you are familiar with, you are not going to be in a position to answer, nor are the questions you are asking going to be useful to those who could.  The poster's original form of the question body, and question as given in its title, was arguably better than what they have done to it in an attempt to satisfy you.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Chris here, so guys if this question has an answer please help me with it, if the android doesn't disclose the actual location of system dropbox then i guess i don't have a choice here.

Comment: @Chris `this question concerns built in functionality of the Android platform`. Good to know.  It would have been nice if the OP had stated that rigth away or after my comments. As he did not I just tried to understand where he was talking about. So i did not yet know if this was 'something i was familiar with'.

Comment: Google doesn't know anything of 'android: system dropbox folder' besides the `getExternalFilesDir()` So I wonder too what kind of folder that would be. And didn't you say in your original post that you wanted to let DropBox sync files in that folder? If so then I'm unaware of dropbox beeing able to sync. The user can only download to that folder as far as i know.

Comment: This is the link google provides about system dropbox folder :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DropBoxManager.html@greenapps , please go and update your knowledge about this.